# Protect Back-End Access database using password

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm using a database divided:

- front-end: contains forms, reports, etc etc;
- back-end: it contains tables;

Now I need to protect the back-end with a simple password.

NOTE: The password must be only on the back end. The front-end must be free access.

Thanks. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect by password a divided  access database is necessary:

1. delete links to the tables from the database front-end;
2. open back-end Database in exclusive mode;
3. insert password;
4. re-link table into front-end database.

this video can help to understand: [Protect divided Access database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXrwumT3JUo)

Answer (score 0):

You really could bing/google on this yourself. Anyway, here's a round-up where #8 covers the password:

[10 tips for securing a Microsoft Access database](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-tips-for-securing-a-microsoft-access-database/)

Comment: Thanks you Gustav but I think that is little different in a divide database. I try your solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I tried your solution, despite I knew it was not working. Next time please do not be hasty. If I log on this platform it means that  I can also access to google. Thanks and best regards.

Comment: If you knew it didn't work, why ask? Anyway, it does work as advertised: Encrypt the backend, link the tables, and you are off.